# Dropping not working on Chrome Mac version

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I tried to work with html5 drag&drop api, and it works very well on my chrome 20.0.1132 on windows machine, but most fun - that the same version of chrome on mac os lion is not working. I mean dragstart is working, but drop event, dragleave, dragover is not fired. 
Here is html:

```
<form id="fake_form" action="#" >
            <div id="canvas_wrapper" style="overflow: hidden;width: 600px; position: relative;border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 30px;">
                <canvas width="600" height="300" >
                </canvas>
            </div>
 </form>
```

Here is javascript:

```
    var canvas = $('canvas')[0];
    canvas.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e){
        console.log('dragenter');
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('dragleave', function(){
        console.log('dragleave');
    }, false)
    canvas.addEventListener('dragover', function(e){
        console.log('dragover');
        if(e.preventDefault){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return false;
    }, false);
    canvas.ondrop = function(e){
        console.log('ondrop');
    /** OTHER CODE **/
```

If it helps: on safari on the same mac - it works, I`m dragging image tags some of them have draggable attribute, some of them - not. Just checked - on canary mac version 22 it works.

**UPDATE:** I figured out that there is some magic with dragstart event, if I delete line 
with this `e.dataTransfer.setData('src', src_var)` everythings become working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for this problem - when you use `e.dataTransfer.setData` the first argument should be the right mime type, i changed it to `text/plain` and everything is become working